# Parse hyphenated word to unsigned integer

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

When tested to_tsvector on 'someword-123' with english full text config, I got the following result:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('someword-123');

to_tsvector
tsvector
--------------------
"'-123':2 'someword':1"
```

However, I want to config to get the result like `"'123':2 'someword':1"` so when user search with `'someword & 123'`, it could return result.

Is there anyway to do this? Hope someone could help.

Update: For more information, my full text search is applied mostly for product name. For example, I have a product which name is `"Intel Core i7-3820 Processor"` and I want the result of `to_tsvector()` for this string could be like `"'intel':1, 'core':2, 'i3':3, '3820':4, 'processor': 5"` (currently, it's `"'intel':1, 'core':2, 'i3':3, '-3820':4, 'processor': 5"`) so this product can be returned when user search with `'intel 3820'`

Thank for your all.

Comment: perhaps a better description of what you're trying to accomplish and why your data is formatted in such a way will get more attention and perhaps some answers. as it stands, i can't really understand the purpose behind your data or the pattern.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to modify the tsearch2 parser, which isn't a fun job. You want tsearch2 to treat mixed number-and-letter hyphenated words the same as normal hyphenated words.

Comment: @swasheck Like Craig said, I want postgre full-text parser treat number-and-letter hyphenated words the same as normal hyphenated words. E.g., I have a product which name is `"Intel Core i7-3820 Processor"` and i want this product could be returned when user search 'intel 3820', i.e. its tsvector could be something like `"'intel':1, 'core':2, 'i3':3, '3820':4, 'processor': 5"`. Thank you.

Comment: This may be a breain-dead idea, but how about pre-processing product names so that spaces replace hyphens?  (Say, you can put it in a separate column.)

Comment: @dezso +1 for your solution. I didn't think of it that way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to work around your problem: simply replace hyphens with spaces in the strings to be `ts_vector`ed.  If necessary, you can store the unhyphenated values in a separate column and run your searches against it.